# Get variables from HTTP and processing it with AppleScript

Tags: http, variables, applescript

I get this result from a website:

Value2: 16
Value4: 34

It is possible to have multiple lines or just one. The value is always separated with a ":". The values should be used in AppleScript like this:

set Value2 to 16
set value4 to 34
...

This is what I have so far:

```
set someText to do shell script "curl http://asdress | textutil -stdin -stdout -format html -convert txt -encoding UTF-8"

set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {":"}
set delimitedList to every text item of someText
```

How can I set the variables individually?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you simulate the output of your `curl` command with `echo` like this:

```
echo -e "Value2: 16\n Value4: 34"

echo -e "Value2: 16 Value4: 34"
```

you can test out some filtering with `grep`. I would go for the following:

```
echo -e "Value2: 16\n Value4: 34" | grep -Ewo "\d+"
```

which will use `Extended Regular Expressions` (`-E`) which allows me to look for one or more digits with `\d+`, and the `-w` says what I find must have a word boundary either side (so that I don't find the `Value2` or `Value4`, and the `-o` says to only output the part that matches.

So, to answer your question, I would change your `curl` to

```
curl .... | grep -Ewo "\d+"
```

and you will just get the output

```
16
34
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't. Either use a map/hash/dictionary/associative list/table structure to store arbitrary key-value pairs, or use `if theKey == "Value1" then \ set Value1 to theValue \ else if theKey == "Value2" then ... etc.` if you have a limited number of known keys and really must use separate variables for some rare reason.

Frustratingly, AppleScript doesn't include a key-value data type - it only has arrays (lists) and structs (records) - but you can easily roll your own quick-n-dirty associative list routines for looping over a list of `{theKey:"...",theValue:"..."}` records (naive performance should be fine up to several dozen items; larger sets'll require more efficient algorithims). Or, if you're on 10.10+ and don't mind getting Cocoa in your AppleScript, you might consider using `NSDictionary`, which isn't totally ideal either but scales efficiently and saves you the hassle of writing your own code.